# Getting No such algorithm exception while using TLSV1.2 in java 1.4

Tags: bouncycastle, tls1.2, java1.4

I am trying to hit a webservice which supports TLSv1.2. I am using Java 1.4. It does not support TLSv1.2.

Now someone told me that BC could solve my problem. 
Though does it work with a SSLEngine as drop in replacement somehow? 
Is this possible with BC?

What do I have to do to get a working `SSLEngine` (for use with TLSv1 in a 
nonblocking io scenario) without such low restrictions on primesize for DH.

What I tried:

```java
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

This alone seems not to solve the problem.

So instead of

```java
SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");  //which works alas only little DH keys.
```

I tried calling the following:

```java
SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1","BC"); 

SSLContext.getInstance("TLS","BC");

SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2","BC");  

SSLContext.getInstance("ssl","BC");
```

Though all of them throws `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

Comment: Release: 1.57 
Date:      2017, May 11 Bouncy castle library says that A higher level TLS API and JSSE provider have been added to the project.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve this by using **bctls** lib, but unfortunatelly it doesn't seem to have a version for **Java 1.4**.

The only version that I could find in [Bouncy Castle's website](http://bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) and in [Mvn Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=bctls) is **bctls-jdk15on-157** (for **Java >= 1.5**).

Anyway, if an upgrade of your Java version is possible, you just need to add this jar to your project and use the `org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider` class (I've used **Java 1.7** for this test):

```java
// add the JSSE provider
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());

// tests
SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

All tests above run without error.

Checking all the SSL protocols supported:

```java
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(context.getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols())); // [TLSv1.1, TLSv1, TLSv1.2]
```

The output is:

> [TLSv1.1, TLSv1, TLSv1.2]

Comment: It looks good but I can't use due to java version issue. BC says that they provides support of TLS to java 1.4 as well. BC comments for 1.57 version: " A higher level TLS API and JSSE provider have been added to the project". I am looking for sample program for java 1.4 which uses TLSv1.2 using bouncycastle.

Comment: I didn't find this information in BC's website (that JSSE is supported in Java 1.4 - there's only a bctls package for Java >= 1.5)

Comment: You can find BC article . Go to section 2.2.3 Additional Features and Functionality .                                    https://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html

Comment: It just says *"A higher level TLS API and JSSE provider have been added to the project"* but it's not clear if it covers all Java versions. If you look at their [maven repo](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle), there's only **bctls** for Java >= 1.5

Comment: I have used bouncycastle jar . Now I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Export restriction: this JSSE implementation is non-pluggable. excpetion.

Comment: I'm not sure what this error is. Maybe if you contact BouncyCastle team? Sorry, I wish I could help you more on that.