# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: TLS1.2 for provider BCJSSE

Tags: java, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I'm using the bouncy castle jar to get TLS1.2 instance but i'm getting the below exception:
>

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: TLS1.2 for provider BCJSSE
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:157)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:281)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:24)
at com.fca.mopar.partSegmentation.service.PartDataService.getRestTemplate(PartDataService.java:108)
at com.fca.mopar.partSegmentation.service.PartDataService.fetchPartInfo(PartDataService.java:161)
at com.fca.mopar.partSegmentation.controllers.MPIMController.partDetails(MPIMController.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
```

Below is the code:

`

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS1.2", Security.getProvider("BCJSSE"));
context.init(null, null, null);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(context).build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

`

We need to call a web-service having TLSv1.2 & our server has lower TLS version hence the handshake is failing.
(JDK : v1.6,  JARS: bcprov-jdk15on-160 , bctls-jdk15on-160 ).
Can someone please help me out or give an example if i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: use  `BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME` instead of fix string "BCJSSE" to get the Provider

Comment: @Jens i tried that as well..

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694197/getting-no-such-algorithm-exception-while-using-tlsv1-2-in-java-1-4